# Extracting sql statements between delimiter ';' using python RE

Tags: python, sql, regex

I have a SQL file with following statements, the statement needs to be extracted

```
select * from customers;

select count(*) from customers;

select a.cust_name,sum(b.revenue) from
customers a join revenue_tab b 
on a.c_id=b.c_id
group by a.cust_name;
```

below is the python code which extracts the sql statements and counts the number of time SELECT keyword appeared in the statement

```
import re

query = {}

def GetTheStatements():
    with open('dummy.sql') as fp:
      for result in re.findall('(.*?);', fp.read(), re.S):
          count_select = sum(1 for x in re.finditer(r"\bselect\b", result))
          q = {result :{ 'count_select': count_select}}
          query.update(q)
    print query

GetTheStatements()
```

but the resultant dictionary will look like this

```
{'\n\nselect count(*) from customers': {'count_select': 1}, '\nselect * from customers': {'count_select': 1}, '  \n\nselect a.cust_name,sum(b.revenue) from\ncustomers a join revenue_tab b \non a.c_id=b.c_id\ngroup by a.cust_name': {'count_select': 1}}
```

How to strip the newline (\n) also sometimes (\r) from it while fetching the statements in the regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have,

```
q = {result :{ 'count_select': count_select}}
```

you could substitute,

```
q = {re.sub(r'[\n\r]', '', result) :{ 'count_select': count_select}}
```